# Hide top space in SwiftUI's NavigationView

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I'm having trouble to remove the top space inside a `NavigationView`.

[image]
[image]

You can see that in the first screen, I have the "Job filters" title, which is later shown in the back button when for example tapping on the `Company` picker, but the space that the title used to occupy is now empty. How can this be removed?

The body's var of the view is:

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                ...
                ...
                Picker("FilterView.Company".localized, selection: $draft.company) {
                    SearchBar(searchText: $searchText)
                    Text("FilterView.Company.AllCompanies".localized).tag(nil as Company?)
                    if searchText.isEmpty {
                        ForEach(companiesFetchedResults) {
                            Text($0.companyName).tag($0 as Company?)
                        }
                    } else {
                        ForEach(companiesFetchedResults.filter {
                            $0.companyName.contains(searchText)
                        }) {
                            Text($0.companyName).tag($0 as Company?)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("FilterViewTitle".localized)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) { cancel }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) { done }
            }
        }
    }
```

### Edit

As suggested by @Stefan I've managed to extract the `Form` into a separate view, but it still doesn't work:

`FilterView`:

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            FormView(draft: $draft)
                .navigationBarTitle("FilterViewTitle".localized)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) { cancel }
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) { done }
                }
        }
    }
```

`FormView`:

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                ...
                ...
                Picker("FilterView.Company".localized, selection: draft.company) {
                    SearchBar(searchText: $searchText)
                    Text("FilterView.Company.AllCompanies".localized).tag(nil as Company?)
                    if searchText.isEmpty {
                        ForEach(companiesFetchedResults) {
                            Text($0.companyName).tag($0 as Company?)
                        }
                    } else {
                        ForEach(companiesFetchedResults.filter {
                            $0.companyName.contains(searchText)
                        }) {
                            Text($0.companyName).tag($0 as Company?)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
```

Comment: use `.navigationBarTitle("Test", displayMode: .inline)`

Comment: I tried, setting this both at the `Form` and the `Picker` level, but the result is that only the first screen shows the tittle (Job filters) in inline mode, but the second screen remains the same

Comment: This is Large title area, if we use it we cannot remove it, but we can fill it with other title like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63591598/12299030. Alternate is to not use large title mode.

Comment: but I'm not changing it on the file; the only one I'm using is `.navigationBarTitle("FilterViewTitle".localized)` as seen in the codde that I pasted above

Answer (score 4):

You need to explicitly set navigationBarTitleDisplayMode to inline, which should solve your problem:

```
.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
```

EDIT:

[Why is there a huge big gap between the back button and the starting element of the view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72085494/why-is-there-a-huge-big-gap-between-the-back-button-and-the-starting-element-of/72085758#72085758)

TL;DR:
Do not embed pushed views in the NavigationView

Comment: it doesn't fix it: it just shows the "Job filters" in an inline mode, but the second screen remains the same :(

Comment: Ah I see. You've embedded it in NavigationView. Just extract the pushed view out of NavigationView: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72085494/why-is-there-a-huge-big-gap-between-the-back-button-and-the-starting-element-of/72085758#72085758

Comment: still, same result when extracting the `Form` to another view and using the `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)`

Comment: @noloman can you share your updated code for the filter view?

Comment: I just updated the original question, thanks!

Comment: @noloman pls try this

```var body: some View {
            FormView(draft: $draft)
                .navigationBarTitle("FilterViewTitle".localized)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) { cancel }
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) { done }
                }
    }
```

Comment: @noloman so basically that you don't embed anything inside of a NavigationView in a pushed view

Comment: if there's no `NavigationView` this doesn't work at all. I want to keep the title in the first screen, which needs a `NavigationView`. Also, without a `NavigationView`, clicking on any picker doesn't work

Comment: Yes, you leave the NavigationView in the root view, but do not use it in the pushed view

Comment: ok I'm not sure anymore what you consider the root view: `FilterView` is being called from another View, in the form of a sheet:

```var filter: some View {
        Button {
            self.showFilter = true
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3.decrease.circle")
                .renderingMode(.original)
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showFilter) {
            FilterView($jobFilter, categoriesViewModel, jobsViewModel)
        }
    }``` 
so I'm not sure if this is the root view as you call it

Comment: if you refer to `FilterView` as the root view, you can see that I'm using a `NavigationView` there but not in the `FormView`

Comment: The view that has title "Jobs filters" should be embedded in the NavigationView, that is what I consider a root view in this case. Pushed view(FilterView) should not contain NavigationView as it will inherit it from the view it is pushed from

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244953/discussion-between-noloman-and-stefan).